# PHP creating invoice jpeg

Tags: php, invoice, invoices

I am creating a web service for my online shop and need to generate invoices, i know how to generate invoice and [pdf](/questions/tagged/pdf) invoice but **what i want to know is how to generate image invoices like [jpg](/questions/tagged/jpg) or [png](/questions/tagged/png) for example**.

Comment: Maybe first you can generate a `PDF` invoice and then convert it to an image using https://github.com/spatie/pdf-to-image ?

Comment: that was a vary good suggestion , tanx

Answer (score 0):

You could try using:
https://github.com/xvilo/invoice-generator
or
https://github.com/Invoiced/invoice-generator-api

Google has many options when searching for "PHP invoice generator".

I hope this helped.